Import an excel workbook with a subject Like 'ABC'
Probably a stupid question but I am a beginner here and there is part of my code which I'm struggling with.  I am trying to import a file from outlook into excel but each day, the filename will change.
e.g

Monday: "FileABC_12345.xls"
Tuesday: "FileABC_52359.xls"
Wednesday: "FileABC_69523.xls"

How do I account for this?
This is what I tried but it does not work:
Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()
    
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim OutlookFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim CurrentOutlookFilter As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutlookItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Attachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim RangeToExtract As Excel.Range
    Dim OutlookFilter As Outlook.View
    Dim InboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim ResultItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iFilterItem As Integer
    Dim sFileDate As String
    
    
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    
    Range("M3") = "No File Yet"
    Range("M4") = "No File Yet"
    
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    
    Set RangeToExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then
    
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        
    End If
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Change to the appropriate folder
    Set InboxItems = OutlookFolder.Items
    Set ResultItems = InboxItems.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject Like '%SubjectofEmail%') AND (urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment=true) AND %yesterday(urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived)%")
    For iFilterItem = 1 To ResultItems.Count
        
        ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
        Set OutlookItem = ResultItems(iFilterItem)
        If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
            
            Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
            
            AttachmentTitles(1) = "FileABC_" & "*" & ".xls"  'THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE!!!!!!!!
            
            AttachmentTitles(2) = "ignore123.xlsx" 'ignore, there is no 2nd attachement
            
            AttachmentTitles(3) = "ignore123.xlsx" 'ignore, there is no 3rd attachement
            
            Dim AttachmentCount As Integer
            
            AttachmentCount = 0
            
            ' Loop through the attachments in the email
            
            For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                For i = 1 To 3
                    
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(i) Then
                    
                        
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
                        
                        ' Create a new Excel application
                        
                        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                        
                        ExcelApp.Visible = False
                        
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i), , , , "123456")
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                        
                        'Add up the column Qs where column T = N and put in cell K3 also print out the datestamp
                        Range("M3") = ExcelWorksheet.Range("C55").Value
                        Range("M4") = Format(sFileDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                        
                        'ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, AttachmentCount * 3) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                        
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        
                        
                        ExcelApp.Quit
                        
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                        
                        Set ExcelApp = Nothing
                        
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                        
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                        
                    End If
                    
                Next i
                
            Next Attachment
            
            ' Exit the loop after processing the email
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next iFilterItem
    

    
    Set OutlookItem = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary Excel files
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)) <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
            On Error GoTo Errorhandler
        End If
        
    Next i
    

finally:
    On Error Resume Next
    'General cleanup
    Exit Sub
    Resume
Errorhandler:
    'On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo finally
    
End Sub


The code you shared only assigns a value to AttachmentTitles. Please share the relevant line(s) where you tried to import  the file, as well as any relevant error message.

We can't help unless you show the rest of your code and explain the specific problem you're having.  "does not work" is not a useful description of  what happens when you run your code. "import a file from outlook" means there is somewhere in your Inbox a mail with an attachment of that name?

Sorry for not being clear. I will paste the code below.  I am essentially attempting to import an excel attachment from my outlook into an excel workbook. As the code stands, there is no error. All it does is print "No File Yet" in cell M3 of the excel workbook because it cannot locate the correct email in my outlook.  If I specify the name of the attachment exactly, the code works fine and the email attachment is successfully imported into my excel workbook. However the filename changes each day per my original query.

I've pasted the full code back in my original query. If anybody has any ideas, let me know, thanks.

Something like If InStr(1, Attachment.Filename, "FileABC_") Then which return True if FileABC_ is contained within the Attachment.Filename. You could also get more exact with something like If Left(Attachment.Filename, 8) = "FileABC_" And Right(Attachment.Filename, 3) = "xls" Then.

@JNevill or you could use Like with a wildcard.

AttachmentTitles(1) = "FileABC_*.xls":...: If Attachment.Filename Like AttachmentTitles(i) Then

Great, thank you for your help! I'll give those a try.
